Trying to figure out the most idiomatic rust way of storing pointer to another struct in outer struct
I have this code right now described in [1]. It throws error described in [2]. I am trying to allocate a really large inner object (think 100s of MBs of bitmap), and would like to directly create it on heap.

Is the most idiomatic way of doing this in Rust via Box::new or Rc<>?
From search, it seems there is no other way of doing this without wrapping the structure with these two, am I right?
Vector certainly does not need this kind of wrapper. How do I make my struct more like Vector, so that it does not need a wrapper to be on heap?

[1]
struct Inner {
    value1: i32,
    value2: i32,
}

pub struct Outer<'a> {
    vectors: Vec<&'a Inner>,
}

impl<'a> Outer<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let inner = Inner {
            value1: 0,
            value2: 0,
        };
        let mut vectors = Vec::new();
        vectors.push(&inner);
        Outer { vectors: vectors }
    }
}


[2]
cannot return value referencing local variable `inner`
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

experiment.rs(17, 22): `inner` is borrowed here


I should also add, I am trying to avoid cloning the inner object when it gets added to vector. That's why I am using Vec<& Inner>.

You don't clone it when you give it to a vector, it gets moved into the vector. Note that items stored in a vector are on the heap. This is such a simple case that the compiler will likely optimize the value to be constructed directly on the heap instead of first on the stack. Rust doesn't yet have placement-new but you can work around that using Vec's ability to give you a MaybeUninit you can populate with new items directly into the heap allocation. This does require unsafe code. I'd only investigate this if the optimizer doesn't elide the stack allocation.

Got it. Thanks for a quick reply. It just feels odd to rely on compiler instead of having direct control of allocation. Hopefully Rust adds a new-like operator.
One more follow up question: does compiler optimize the allocation directly to heap, or will this create inner object on stack first and then adding it to vector will move it to heap?

Adding to @cdhowie comment: OP can avoid unsafe even if the compiler does not elide the stack-to-heap move (which it probably will), as i32 is such a simple type. let mut v = vec![Inner { value1: 0, value2: 0}; length]; will optimize to a single allocation, which can then be updated.

What does wrapping the pointer in Box<> do? Is it a signal for compiler to move to heap? Or does the Box implementation internally move from stack to heap? I am trying to understand if there is any copy/re-allocate effort at all at any point in time.

It moves the pointer to the heap, but not the value. That pointer is still pointing to the value on the stack, which is why you get that error. I encourage you read the basic docs on references.



Is the most idiomatic way of doing this in Rust via Box::new or Rc<>?


Depends on your situation. Box is the equivalent of std::unique_ptr on C++, in case C++ equivalents help you. Rc is the equivalent of std::shared_ptr in C++.
But the content of a Vec is automatically on the heap, so none of this is required, you can directly move the object into the Vec.


From search, it seems there is no other way of doing this without wrapping the structure with these two, am I right?


I'm not entirely sure what you mean with 'doing this' - if you mean 'putting it on the heap', there are many ways. Among them are Box<> (a non-reference-counted owned object on the heap), Rc<> (a reference counted shared object on the heap), Vec<> (many non-reference-counted owned objects that live together on the heap).


Vector certainly does not need this kind of wrapper. How do I make my struct more like Vector, so that it does not need a wrapper to be on heap?


Vec already stores its items on the heap. It's the equivalent of std::vector in C++.

Your usage of references indicates that you did not fully understand what references actually are, and how to use them. You might want to re-read the docs about referenes.
Your main incorrect assumption is that a reference somehow keeps the original value alive. This is not true; this is what Rc is for.
What actually happens is that your inner object will get destroyed at the end of Outer::new(). Then, the reference stored in the Vec will point to an object that does not exist any more, which causes undefined behavior. As non-unsafe Rust does not contain undefined behavior by definition, the compiler will not allow you to compile this code.
Note that this is not a Rust issue; the exact same code in C++ (well, the syntax adjusted version) will compile, but it will in fact be undefined behavior.

Be aware that your inner object does not live on the heap. So whatever you do, you will need to move it to the heap in some way anyway.
The most trivial and, in my opinion, recommended way is to simply move it to the Vec, like so:
struct Inner {
    value1: i32,
    value2: i32,
}

pub struct Outer {
    vectors: Vec<Inner>,
}

impl Outer {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let inner = Inner {
            value1: 0,
            value2: 0,
        };
        let mut vectors = Vec::new();
        vectors.push(inner);
        Outer { vectors }
    }
}



One more follow up question: does compiler optimize the allocation directly to heap, or will this create inner object on stack first and then adding it to vector will move it to heap?

Yes and no. It is indeed true that there is no simple equivalent to C++'s new operator. The closest you would get is Box::new(Inner{...}), but technically this still gets compiled to two steps:

Creation of the Inner object
Moving it to the heap through Box::new

In practice, this will get compiled into an in-place creation, but it is in fact a compiler optimization that you do not have control over.
I do agree that this is a shortcoming of Rust that should get solved some day.
This is not an issue in most cases, but it did already bite me when I tried to create large static arrays on the heap; Box::new([0u8; 100000000]) does in fact cause a stack overflow error as it does not create the array directly on the heap.
There are some discussions here and here.
There was even an RFC that was rejected here, but the team keeps working on it.
The most recent update I found was here:

Placement new will likely be an optimization for Box, Vec, etc, and they may get new methods to specify the address.


Thanks for the detailed reply.
"Your main incorrect assumption is that a reference somehow keeps the original value alive. This is not true; this is what Rc is for." => yeah I am not using reference for keeping the value alive. I thought vector did that, but I understand now that vector needs non-referenced value to keep value alive. This is all done in a very confusing way in Rust.
"Box::new([0u8; 100000000]) does in fact cause a stack overflow error as it does not create the array directly on the heap."
This is exactly what I am trying to accomplish, but slightly different.

"This is all done in a very confusing way in Rust" - not really, it follows a pretty straight forward system. I recommend reading the ownership chapter in the Rust book, it explains it pretty well.

@Parth You'd just need to do vec![0e8; 100000000] instead. This will create a Vec<u8>. No array will be allocated on the stack in this case.

@cdhowie That doesn't work with large objects that have a constructor, though.

@Finomnis I never said it did.

@cdhowie that's my use-case here. I want to allocate lots of inner objects (probably sized 1kb-64kb) and add them to vector. It seems, I don't control how and where they will be allocated. And if they are allocated on stack then they will be copied to heap as part of vector.push call. This is not desirable but I will work with that. Thanks for detailed replies! I will close this question now.

If the inner objects are variably sized, then it's highly usecase dependent. To help you further, we need a more representative [MRE].
